# Can I get a stack trace for un-handled (Objective) C++ exceptions?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, exception

I'm developing an iOS application that has recently grown a large C++ base. C++ is not my forte, and I'm getting frustrated by exceptions. What I'm looking for is a way to get a stack track to the site of an (un-handled) exception throw. I'll say that the "un-handled" qualifier is optional; I would settle for breaking on *any* exception throw as a last resort, though un-handled exceptions are ideal.

What I currently get is useless. Assuming I don't have any appropriate exception handlers higher up the callstack, and I do something like

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
my_vector.at(40) = 2; // Throws std::out_of_range
```

The app will break in `main()` and I'll get a log message saying "terminate called throwing an exception." Not helpful.

Putting generic try/catch blocks higher up the callstack doesn't help either, because the callstack is unwound during exception handling up to the point of the catch block, leaving me ignorant to actual origin of the exception. This also applies to providing my own `terminate_handler`. Asserts are more useful, but they require me to anticipate error conditions to some extent, which I cannot always do. I would still like the debugger to be able to step in even if an unexpected exception makes it past my pre-emptive `assert()`s.

What I want to avoid is having to wrap every call that might possibly throw an exception in a try/catch block just to get the stack trace to the error. At runtime, I'm really not interested in catching these exceptions. When they occur, it means there's a fatal flaw in the program execution, and there's no way it can continue normally. I just want to be notified so I can determine the cause and mend the issue so it won't happen again.

---

In Objective C, I can put a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`, and any time I screw something up I'll immediately break execution and be presented with a nice stack trace so I know where the issue is. Very helpful.

I realize this behavior is really only useful because of a philosophical difference in exception handling between the two languages. Objective C exceptions are intended only to signify unrecoverable errors. The task of routine error handling is accomplished via error return codes. This means that *any* Objective C exception is a great candidate for a breakpoint to the developer.

C++ seems to have a different use for Exceptions. They're used to handle both fatal errors *and* routine errors (at least in the 3rd party libs I'm using). This means I might not actually want to break on every exception that's thrown in C++, but I would still find the ability useful if I can't break only on un-handled exceptions.

Comment: C++ exceptions aren't really intended for _routine_ errors, but they do get overused sometimes. It's true that they're not solely for unrecoverable errors though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quickly establish a break on all C++ throw conditions in Xcode:

- `cmd+6`
- "**+**" button -> Add Exception Breakpoint
- - C++ -> `std::out_of_range`
- - On Throw

**Update**

If you have a lot of them tho filter out, you may prefer to:

- Create a Symbolic Breakpoint
- Symbol = `__cxa_throw` (may vary by std library)
- Action > Debugger Command =  `bt`
- Automatically continue after eval = On

The `bt` command logs the backtrace. Configured this way, it will automatically continue.

So, this will just log the backtrace of every thrown exception - when your program terminates due to an unhandled exception, the clues will be among the final logged backtraces (often the last, unless the library rethrows).

Comment: And yet I struggle. It seems like you should be able to specify only certain exceptions to break upon. I'm using ZXing, which throws exceptions absolutely everywhere (Several per-frame, during normal operation). I need to ignore these. However, when I set a breakpoint on something completely unrelated like `std::out_of_range`, the breakpoint is still triggered on all ZXing's std::exception subclasses. Is this normal?

Comment: Okay, so if I grasp this correctly, the debugger should break on any exception throw, log the backtrace, then automatically continue? The merit of this approach being that I can just read back through all the recent exception stack traces to find only the ones I care about?

Comment: @MattWilding exactly. if you set it up as outlined, it will just print without pausing. then your issues would lie at the end of the output, which will (typically) allow you to locate the problem relatively quickly.

Comment: That makes sense, however Xcode (GDB) seems to stop execution regardless of the "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" setting. I've tried on several breakpoints. It also seems like the "named" setting for C++ Exception Breakpoints is intended to allow breaking only on specific exceptions, but it's not respected either.

Comment: @MattWilding Strange, it works as I've described on Xc4.2 + 10.6.8. Oh! Did you see that the second option is using *symbolic* breakpoints?

Comment: Oh joy. Well, everything you said sounds totally valid, so green check for you. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

In the app I get to debug with many c++ exceptions, I leave the "Catch C++ Exceptions on Throw" off until I get to the point in the app where it will throw the exception, then I turn that option on and usually the next exception that is thrown is what I'm looking for. This will break a few levels deeper than where the error is, but the stack is intact so you can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). We use it with our application (which relies heavily on C++) and it produces stack traces even for the C++ code.

The only problem you might have is when using assembly routines which were not written natively for iOS (Apple's compiler is using R7 to hold the stack frame for tracing back symbols which is not according to official ARM EBI)